# How to Print the stream directly without storing it in anywhere in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

All,

I have a stream, when user clicks a button on my page I need to print the stream without storing it anywhere. How can i acheive this?

Thanks.

Comment: a stream of what - video, image, pdf, text, etc?  and do you want to display it on the screen, or print it to a physical printer?

Comment: I want to print the stream of Image in a printer (on a paper) and not to store it on my device.

Comment: what kind of printer, and what OS?  Printing is very platform/device specifc

Comment: I just only have stream and I don't want to write or store it anywhere. I am using Xamarin forms. I need to do it for all platforms (Android, iOS and UWP). Is this possible to print raw stream in Xamarin forms?

Comment: no, there is no cross-platform printing framework, and further can be very dependent on the actual printer being used

Comment: Then is this possible in xamarin.Android if not in cross platform? Moreover I would like to know whether stream can printed directly without writing it in a file.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos

Comment: From what I understand from your question what you want to do is quite broad and platform specific with almost no tools available. You will have to write a lot and i seriously mean a lot of code for this for almost every device you will have to write something

Answer (score 0):

You may use jsPDF to create PDF document (in memory) and then PDF document viewer will have the facility to print/download the document as supported by the device on which app is running.